# Фильтрация $_FILES от XSS

Tags: php, xss

В наличии строка кода:
`$file_data = file_get_contents($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$key])`;

Каким образом можно отфильтровать данную строку (по тесту - является XSS-уязвимостью).

Comment: используйте white list. Проверяйте тип файла. И вот ещё статья http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950331/secure-php-file-upload-script

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade Проблема в том, что я не знаю, какие типы файлов могут быть загружены, нет доступа ни к самому проекту, ни к базе, ни к ТЗ. Есть один файл с исходником и выявленная уязвимость. Есть ли какой-то универсальный фильтр (может htmlspecialchars)?